# Facebook API Fatal Error

Tags: facebook, api, stream, publish

I am getting the following error with some code that I am using. The error is

> [Mon Jun 27 16:44:04 2011] [error]
>   [client 194.116.198.179] PHP Fatal
>   error:  Call to a member function
>   api() on a non-object in
>   /public_html/users/fbmain.php on line
>   89

The code I am using worked ok before I made it into a function. Line 89 begins with $statusUpdate.

```
function post_basic_status($msg){
    try {
        $statusUpdate = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array('message'=> $msg));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        d($e);
    }
}
```

From looking online I cannot find any solution to this. IS there anything glaringly wrong with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue... until your post about calling the api from a function.
It turns our that Facebook API doesn't like to be used in a function.
It needs to be called on page load.

Comment: Yeah worked that out in the end, should have updated the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was scratching my head until I read this post... the problem is that $facebook is declared outside the function and is being referenced inside the function but is not recognized.

You either need to pass the $facebook handle in as a parameter OR add the line GLOBAL $facebook; at the top of the function.

Answer (score 0):

add the line GLOBAL $facebook; at the top of the function. it worked for me :)